# Is there an "inverse law of large numbers"?

Tags: law-of-large-numbers

The different laws of large numbers that I've seen state that

> 1. If conditions $K$ holds
> 2. Then the sample average of a process X_n converges in probability/almost-surely, to $\mu$.

**Is there an inverse of this?**

> 1. If conditions $L$ **do not** hold
> 2. Then the sample averges **does not** converge in probability nor almost surely, to anything.

**Or even better:**

> 1. If and only if conditions $M$ hold
> 2. ....

Basically, what I'd like to know is, whether it is known under what conditions the law of large numbers does not apply.

Comment: So you want a statement which is equivalent to "The sample average converges [in probability / almost surely] to $\mu$" but not trivially so?

Comment: @Arthur, basically, what I want to know is, whether it is known under what conditions the law of large numbers does not apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An interesting converse is the following:  if $\{X_n\}$ is an i.i.d sequence of non-negative random variables such that $\frac {S_n} n \to a$ almost surelyfor some $a>0$ then  $E|X_n| < \infty$ and $a=EX_1$. Thus finiteness of the mean is a necessary condition for SLLN's. To prove that just apply ordinary SLLN to the i.i.d. sequence $\min \{{X_n, k}\}$ and note that $\min \{{X_n, k}\} \leq X_n$ to conclude that $E\min \{{X_n, k}\}$ is bounded as $k \to \infty$. By fatou's Lemma we get $EX_1 <\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial counterexample is obtained if you drop the independence condition: take all samples being equal to the first one, and convergence will be to that value instead of to the mean. (More generally, dependence can imply a bias on the mean or even non-convergence.)